# Push an integer into an array from a function result

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I push totalNumber in myFunction into the myArray  over a number of times so that it creates a log of entries  in the array?

```
myFunction(){
     var start =  document.getElementById('name1').value;
     var end  = document.getElementById('name2').value;
     let totalNumber = end - start;
     //document.getElementById('name3').textContent = totalNumber;
     document.getElementById('congrats').textContent = "congrats you read " +  totalNumber  + "  pages today!";

}

const myArray = [];
```

Comment: [Check out the docs on .push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

Comment: @Chris please return to your question and interact with us

Comment: @mplungjan, thanks for the edit, I like the conversion into E6.  However I haven't yet gone to my IDE to test, but will give feedback as soon as I do.  At a glance this looks like what I am looking for, but the test will tell.  I am trying to develop my first app after studying pure Vanilla JS for almost 1.5 years without writing anything of my own, and I have a clear mind on what I want to do.  Next I want to link the array stats into an HTML div that will show the totalNumber in a block that cascades downwards at each click(maybe with a date) - but as we say, one thing at a time. Back soon!

Answer (score 0):

The code below will push the value to the array each time it is called

```js
const myArray = [];
const myFunction = () => {
  var start =  document.getElementById('name1').value;
  var end  = document.getElementById('name2').value;
  let totalNumber = end - start; // the subtraction makes the sum an integer if strings contain integers
  myArray.push(totalNumber);
  document.getElementById('congrats').textContent = "Congrats, you read " +  totalNumber  + "  pages today!";
}
```

You can use localStorage to persist the array

Note your .value will be a string so you need to convert to number using for example parseInt, parseFloat or Number.
However if we perform some action that casts the strings to number, your result is a number too. That could be subtraction, multiplication or division. If you add, however, if a string is involved you do need to convert first to not concatenate. A leading plus will convert: So `myArray.push(+someString)` where `+someString` has same effect as `Number(someString)`

Comment: _push totalNumber in myFunction into the myArray over a number of times so that it creates a log of entries_ now please remove your vendetta vote

Comment: Why use let? Const doesn't dictate immutability on arrays and I haven't heard the argument that it should before. If the reference point shouldn't change, why not let Javascript enforce that and throw an error on reassignment by using const?

Comment: Thanks a lot I will try that and give feedback when I get to my laptop, but it looks excellent at a glance!

Comment: Keep in mind, that all values stored in <HTMLInputElement> are strings. When you grab values from inputs, which in your case are saved to `start` and `end`, you should first convert them to numbers using `parseInt` or `parseFloat`, then proceed with subtraction.

Comment: @AlexTymchuk unless you perform some action that casts them to number, such as subtraction, multiplication and division. If you add, however, if a string is involved you do need to convert to not concatenate. A leading plus will convert: So `myArray.push(+someString)` +someString has same effect as Number(someString)

Comment: @Maria using TypeScript, const is really treated like a const. So I am used to NOT add anything to a const.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your code to the following:

```
const myArray = [];
myFunction(){
  var start =  document.getElementById('name1').value;
  var end  = document.getElementById('name2').value;
  let totalNumber = end - start;
  myArray.push(totalNumber);
  //document.getElementById('name3').textContent = totalNumber;
  document.getElementById('congrats').textContent = "congrats you read " +  totalNumber  + "  pages today!";

}
```

This is because variables declared using let or const don't hoist. So you need to declare it before the function.

Also above code will assume, integer is input in the textbox. If it is integer, the subtraction operation will first convert them to integer. If they are not integers, it will give NaN. So you should add proper validation on those textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys apologies for taking so long to some back.  The JS is working perfectly, but now I am having a hard time trying to display the array in an HTML div so that it aligned as a block:

This is my html:

```
  <div id="rightpane">
        <p>Stats</p>   
    </div>
```

This is my CSS

```
#rightPane
{
width:20%;
margin-right: 30px;
margin-top: 8%;
/* background-color: grey;  */
float: right;
height: auto;
padding: 5px;
text-align: center;
display: block;
}
```

And this is the JS

```
//Array to hold statistics of number of pages read per sitting  over a period of time
const myArray = [];
//Function to calculate number of pages read
const calculate = () => {
  var start = document.getElementById("number1").value;
  var end = document.getElementById("number2").value;
  let totalNumber = end - start; 
  myArray.push(totalNumber); //Push total number into array
  document.getElementById("congrats").textContent =
    "Congrats, you read " + totalNumber + "  pages today!";//display message
  document.getElementById("rightpane").textContent = myArray;//push array into HTML
};
```

I would really appreciate for more tips on how to execute this